# Arrayresult to single each variables PHP ?

Tags: php

Hey i have this code which is detecting and extract Hashtags.

but i get all in one Array but i need them as singele variabeles to put them for each into the Database.

```
$str = ' xD #lol and #testing and #wtf';
$regex = '/#(\w+)/';
preg_match_all($regex, $str, $allMatches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
//print_r($allMatches);
foreach ($allMatches as $matches) {

   echo $matches[0].'<br>';

  }
```

This is the Result

```
#lol
#testing
#wtf
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function and make a string for saving.
When you need to read array you can convert your string with `explode`

**Example:**

```
$array = array('lastname', 'email', 'phone');
$comma_separated = implode(",", $array);

echo $comma_separated; // lastname,email,phone
```

Comment: iam a bit confused :D 
I have a Array with 3 words,,, 
How to seperate them when there is no comma ?

Comment: @MaddyS. When you use implode first params is glue(comma,pipe) and function add it after every element of array and build a string.... I hope I have helped you to understand :)